# neo4j cypher: modeling a linked list; why use *both* a "NEXT" and a "PREVIOUS" relationship between nodes in a linked list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Ian Robinson's book [Graph Databases](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f511/7084ca43e888fb3e17ab0f0e684cced0f8fd.pdf) on page 73, he states: "We can use NEXT and/or PREVIOUS relationships (depending on our preference)..."

My question: what benefit is there to implementing *both*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit, it will just increase the store sizes on disk.

Cypher will behave the same in traversing one way or the other.

In some cases you will also want a `LAST` relationship, like :

```
(User)-[:LAST_EVENT]->(:Click)-[:PREVIOUS]->(:Click)-[:ETC....
```

Where you can choose to have an additional `LAST_EVENT` relationship between user and the last event, so there will be also a `PREVIOUS` relationship between those two nodes.